# PHP Permission Denied Errors

Tags: php, linux, apache, xampp, smarty

I'm trying to troubleshoot this error, but I have had no luck.

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in Users/myuser/Sites/mysite.me/git/framework/libs/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php
```

I keep getting the `mkdir() [function.mkdir]: permission denied` error in one particular folder. I have made sure to `chmod 777 foldername` through linux and it still hasn't worked. I am doing this on a local machine through XAMPP. I've also made sure to make sure it is read and write for everyone from a GUI standpoint. I'm still having no luck. Thoughts?

I'm getting a warning for `mkdir`, `chmod`, `touch`, `rename`, and `include`.

Comment: Remember that you'll also need `+x` on the parent directories—do you have that?

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Lion. The parent directory of smarty has drwxrwxrwx. How would I add a +x?

Comment: check your parent directory permission specifically the htdocs

Comment: Based on the structure, it looks like OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anybody who ends up here from there:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801733/php-upload-outside-web-root-permission-denied-to-mkdir was marked as an *exact duplicate* of this thread. That thread was also cross-posted to the AWS forums where it [received an answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106428&tstart=0).

---

That said, the accepted answer here is actually *wrong*. (Maybe not *wrong* wrong, but still somewhat wrong.) The better way to approach this is to have the owner/group of the Apache process match the owner/group of the directory that you want Apache (and in-turn, PHP) to be able to write to.

This way, you're granting access to *specific, managed users* instead of opening up your file system permissions too broadly.

Answer (score 0):

Add write permissions for all users (or at least webserver user eg. www-data for apache) in which mkdir is creating the directory.

Comment: Are you referring to chmod 777 the parent directory of the file?

Comment: no, you have the change permissions of directory where "mkdir" is creating a directory.